# css remove inherited list styles

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have css code like this

```
<ul class="simple-list">                                
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li>Paper</li>
        <li>Pen</li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li>Paper</li>
        <li>Pencil</li>
     </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now when I use style like this

```
.simple-list li {
border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE;
display: block;
}
```

It affects all child li elements too. Can someone tell me how to make it affect only the first li element. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
.simple-list li:first-child {
```

You can [check support for first-child on caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=first-child)

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean only the immediate li children of .simple-list (i.e the first level)? or just the first one? If it's immediate children only you want

```
.simple-list > li
```

For just the first one you want @Steve Fenton's answer above